# A tensorflow eager gpu error

Tags: tensorflow

I'm learning the [demo](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/models/blob/master/samples/outreach/demos/eager_execution.ipynb) of tensorflow eager execution. When I tried the cell "GPU usage" (see below), there is an error saying the variable is not placed on GPU.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
tf.enable_eager_execution()
A = tf.constant([[2.0, 0.0], [0.0, 3.0]])
if tf.test.is_gpu_available() > 0:
    with tf.device(tf.test.gpu_device_name()):
        print(tf.matmul(A, A))
```

Full error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 4, in 
>       print(tf.matmul(A, A))
>
> File
>   "c:\python\python35_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py",
>   line 2108, in matmul
>       a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
>
> File
>   "c:\python\python35_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py",
>   line 4517, in mat_mul
>       _six.raise_from(_core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
>
> File "", line 3, in raise_from
>
> InvalidArgumentError: Tensors on conflicting devices: cannot compute
>   MatMul as input #0 was expected to be on
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 but is actually on
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 (operation running on
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0) Tensors can be copied
>   explicitly using .gpu() or .cpu(), or transparently copied by using
>   tfe.enable_eager_execution(tfe.DEVICE_PLACEMENT_SILENT). Copying
>   tensors between devices may slow down your model [Op:MatMul] name:
>   MatMul/

Following the instruction, I tried `tfe.enable_eager_execution(tfe.DEVICE_PLACEMENT_SILENT)`, but it returned another error message (the value returned from `tfe.DEVICE_PLACEMENT_SILENT` was `2`):

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       tfe.enable_eager_execution(tfe.DEVICE_PLACEMENT_SILENT)
>
> File
>   "c:\python\python35_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 5229, in enable_eager_execution
>       "config must be a tf.ConfigProto, but got %s" % type(config))
>
> TypeError: config must be a tf.ConfigProto, but got

How to solve the errors? I also don't know how does `Tensors can be copied explicitly using .gpu() or .cpu()` work.

Thanks.

---

Thanks to @ash, the revised code works (need to restart the notebook).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
tfe.enable_eager_execution(device_policy=tfe.DEVICE_PLACEMENT_SILENT)
A = tf.constant([[2.0, 0.0], [0.0, 3.0]])
if tf.test.is_gpu_available() > 0:
    with tf.device(tf.test.gpu_device_name()):
        print(tf.matmul(A, A))
```

Alternatively (need to restart the notebook),

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
tfe.enable_eager_execution()
A = tf.constant([[2.0, 0.0], [0.0, 3.0]])
if tf.test.is_gpu_available() > 0:
    with tf.device(tf.test.gpu_device_name()):
        A = A.gpu()
        print(tf.matmul(A, A))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The fix described in the error message could certainly use a tweak, try:

> `tfe.enable_eager_execution(device_policy=tfe.DEVICE_PLACEMENT_SILENT)`

instead (notice the use of the `device_policy` keyword argument).

- The other suggestion there was to use the `.cpu()` or `.gpu()` methods, so something like:

> ```
> A = A.gpu()
> print(tf.matmul(A, A))
> ```

- That seems like an error in the demo. But what's happening here is that the tensor `A` is placed in CPU memory and we're asking for the matrix multiplication to execute on the GPU. So, the `A` tensor has to be copied from CPU (a.k.a. "host") memory to GPU (a.k.a. "device") memory. That can be done explicitly, or by setting the `device_policy` argument to `enable_eager_execution()` - the TensorFlow runtime can be told to silently copy tensors between devices when needed.

Hope that helps.